# What word to use with “different” as a comparative

Tags: word-choice

Why do many British people say “different TO”, and many Americans say “different THAN”?  Both of these are grammatically incorrect.

In fact, “Different” always takes FROM”. A good way to remember this is to turn the phrase around by using different as a verb, per the example below:

We do NOT say:

“The way this car differs TO that car is…”

nor

“The way this car differs THAN that car is…”

We say:
“The way this car differs FROM that car is…”

Comment: If you know this, why ask? Just to scold, or identify idiots among us?

Comment: None of the above.